# "quae haec mihi dōna dedistī"

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In the story "Atalanta" in *Fābulae Syrae* by Luigi Miraglia, Venus gives Hippomenes three golden apples to throw during a foot race with Atalanta, to distract her. As he throws the third apple, he says (p. 24, ll. 89–90):

> Nunc adiuvā mē, ō Venus, **quae** haec mihi dōna dedistī!

What does **quae** mean here? If I translate the sentence literally into English, I get:

> Now help me, O Venus, **which** these gifts you gave me!

That doesn't seem to make sense. Or is **quae** actually the feminine singular here?—"Now help me, O Venus, **who** (you) gave me these gifts!" That seems strange, especially with the 2nd-person verb *dedistī,* but I suppose it makes sense. Could **quae** be an appositive here?—"Now help me, O Venus, thou **who** gavest me these gifts!"

Comment: Yes, *quae* is nom. sing. f. and its antecedent is *Venus*

Comment: There's [an older unanswered question on second person verbs in relative clauses](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6271/79) that seems related.

Comment: @Ben Kovitz: Context? It may be "these things which you gave me as gifts"; "these things" could be feminine.

Comment: @tony If *quae* is an object, it has to be neuter plural. If it's nominative, then it can be feminine (singular or plural) or neuter (plural). If the gifts are feminine, then it's *quas*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Quae* in that sentence is feminine nominative singular: *Now help me, O Venus, who gave me these gifts!*

The verb is in the second person because it refers to the second person. The syntactic structure is not inherently different from that of other relative clauses. [Even in old-fashioned English, we can see this agreement pattern in relative clauses (e.g. “thee, who art”)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/481441/is-who-art-correct).